# Insert CSS to <head> before DOM ready?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

**Question:** how can I apply CSS styles BEFORE dom ready, so that the DOM loads already applied with them , **IF** *chrome.storage.sync.get('gacMakeup')* is equal to 1?

I've been using [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) chrome extension to create custom css styles to some of my company internal pages, and now I'm trying to create a chrome extension of my own to apply and share those styles with my colleagues.

While using the Stylish extension, the DOM loads perfectly already with the styles applied and I'd like to have this same effect on my extension. I've tried appending the css code using jQuery, but since I've used $('head').append(); obviously it didn't work because it loads after the dom is ready.

I have an *eventpage.js* to set a **var** called **gacMakeup** using chrome.storage.sync that will be used for on/off toggles. In this case, I'm using the code below to set var to 1 on first opening:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('gacMakeup', function(checkMakeup){
    if (checkMakeup.gacMakeup == undefined) {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({'gacMakeup': '1'});
    };  
});
```

This is the CSS code inside makeup.css that I'd like to apply if gacMakeup == 1:

```
'.lia-stats-area {display: none !important;}
'#lia-body td, #lia-body th {padding: 14px 25px !important;}
'thead#columns {display: none !important;}
'div#pager, div#pager_0 {padding-top: 18px !important;}
'.message-subject-body.wrapper-hide-overflow.message-body.justify {font-size: 13px !important;}
'.lia-info-area {font-size: 11px !important;}
'.lia-list-row.lia-row-odd:hover, .lia-list-row.lia-row-even:hover {background-color: #E3F2FD !important;}
```

This is my manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "__MSG_appName__",
  "description": "__MSG_appDescription__",
  "version": "1.0",
  "author": "Autor",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab", "storage", "notifications", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {"scripts": ["js/eventpage.js"],"persistent": false},
  "web_accessible_resources": ["menu.html"],
  "default_locale": "en",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "styles"
  },

  "icons": {"48": "icon.png"},

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "css": ["css/menu.css"],
      "js": ["js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" ,"js/menu.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate since I'm not trying to attach CSS file right away. I'm trying to attach file if chrome.storage.sync.get is == 1

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry for that.

Comment: Stylish adds to `document.documentElement` when there is no `document.head`. Also, you can access chrome.storage.sync in your content script.

Comment: Can you provide some guidance or reference for my to follow? I'm really on early stages of programming, so I don't really know what that mean :( This is pure JS right?

Comment: Stylish's code is available on github, easily googlable: "stylish extension source code" (see its manifest.json to find which file is a content script).  And yes, jQuery isn't needed to append styles.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the script to be executed before the page is loaded.

```
"content_scripts": [ {
 "js": [ "styles.js" ],
 "run_at": "document_start",
 "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
 } ]
```

Alternatively, since you are only injecting styles, you can apply them using a css file.

```
"content_scripts": [ {
 "css": [ "styles.css" ],
 "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
 } ]
```

You can also only apply the styles if some condition is met via the background page.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid) {
 if(true) {
  chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabid, { file: "styles.css" })
} })
```

Documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts, https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS

Comment: So nice, so simple! I was concerned on how do achieve that with jquery and didn't think it was possible by changing the manifest. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: how can I tie that with a on/off toggle? I'm using chrome.storage.sync.set({'pageStyle': '1'}); and I'd like to load the css only if pageStyle == 1.

Comment: You will need to do that in the background page, see update.

Comment: Since background pages keep running all the time, do I require background exactly or there's a way to do this using eventpages (activated only when called)?

Comment: Persistence doesnt matter for most Chrome apis, it will work the same in most cases.

Comment: The big question now: how can I make the *chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabid, { file: "styles.css" })* to run BEFORE dom load, like "document_start" if I were to do from the manifest directly?

Comment: You can specify that in the function, check the link.

Comment: The function works, but it loads after dom load so elements are flickering when page receives my style.css file. Ideally I'd have this running **before** dom load. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Even when you specify run at document start?

Comment: Yes, even so. I have a eventpage.js that have your script, and I included the "document_start" like so: *chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabid, {file: 'css/mystyle.css', runAt: 'document_start'})*, but I think so problem is the execution of the event page that probable comes after the dom. Is there a way to specify "document_start" for the **"background"** on the manifest? I couldn't find anything related to that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use jquery for that.

Try this:

```
var styleEl = document.createElement('style');

styleEl.innerText = '.lia-stats-area {display: none !important;}' +
'#lia-body td, #lia-body th {padding: 14px 25px !important;} ' +
'thead#columns {display: none !important;}' +
'div#pager, div#pager_0 {padding-top: 18px !important;}' +
'.message-subject-body.wrapper-hide-overflow.message-body.justify {font-size: 13px !important;}' +
'.lia-info-area {font-size: 11px !important;}' +
'.lia-list-row.lia-row-odd:hover, .lia-list-row.lia-row-even:hover{background-color: #E3F2FD !important;}';

document.head.appendChild(styleEl);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This code effect is the same as mine, but it still loads AFTER dom is ready. I'm trying to apply the styles BEFORE DOM ready, so that dom loads  already with style applied, without any flickering effect.